# Reuse the hash-key and generate csv ready format

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to create an csv ready output with jq, and want to reuse the nested hash key on the way.

In this example http, https should be reused to generate csv ready format `([][]...)`.

**Original**

```
{
   "google.com":{
      "https":{
         "dest_url":"http://aaa.com"
      }
   },
   "microsoft.com":{
      "http":{
         "dest_url":"http://bbb.com"
      },
      "https":{
         "dest_url":"http://ccc.com"
      }
   }
}
```

**Expected**

```
[
  "https://google.com",
  "http://aaa.com"
]
[
  "http://microsoft.com",
  "http://bbb.com",
]
[
  "https://microsoft.com",
  "http://ccc.com"
]
```

**What I tried**

```
to_entries[] | [.key, .value[].dest_url]
```

```
[
  "google.com",
  "http://aaa.com"
]
[
  "microsoft.com",
  "http://bbb.com",
  "http://ccc.com"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you separate accessing `.key` and the iteration over `.value[]`, you'll get the cartesian product:

```sh
jq 'to_entries[] | [.key] + (.value[] | [.dest_url])'
```

```json
[
  "google.com",
  "http://aaa.com"
]
[
  "microsoft.com",
  "http://bbb.com"
]
[
  "microsoft.com",
  "http://ccc.com"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/P-yH7TK9g6)

---

To include the nested keys, it's easier to save the outer `.key` before descending with the inner `to_entries`:

```sh
jq 'to_entries[] | .key as $key | .value | to_entries[] | [.key + "://" + $key, .value.dest_url]'
```

```json
[
  "https://google.com",
  "http://aaa.com"
]
[
  "http://microsoft.com",
  "http://bbb.com"
]
[
  "https://microsoft.com",
  "http://ccc.com"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UIn9Fg48rL)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is a big learning for me. However, I expect the first element in the array has to have `http://`, or `https://` as prefix depending on the nested hash key.

Comment: It is amazing! I'll go back to the official page and try to understand your answer.